# Google Assistant Smarthome: Query for fan speed always fail

Tags: actions-on-google

Developing fan trait for Google Actions, query for the status of the fan always returns fail. Here is my step:

**Sync**

`{
    "id": "d25dde36-76cb-44aa-a649-b1f61bb3bebb",
    "type": "action.devices.types.FAN",
    "traits": ["action.devices.traits.OnOff", "action.devices.traits.FanSpeed"],
    "name": {
        "name": "living room fan"
    },
    "willReportState": false,
    "attributes": {
        "availableFanSpeeds": {
            "ordered": true,
            "speeds": [{
                "speed_name": "low",
                "speed_values": [{
                    "lang": "en",
                    "speed_synonym": ["low"]
                }]
            }, {
                "speed_name": "medium",
                "speed_values": [{
                    "lang": "en",
                    "speed_synonym": ["medium"]
                }]
            }, {
                "speed_name": "high",
                "speed_values": [{
                    "lang": "en",
                    "speed_synonym": ["high"]
                }]
            }]
        }
    },
    "deviceInfo": {
        "manufacturer": "XYZ"
    },
    "customData": {
        "serialID": "001D10010334",
        "type": "resource"
    }
}`

**Query**

`{"inputs":[{"intent":"action.devices.QUERY","payload":{"devices":[{"customData":{"serialID":"001D10010334","type":"resource"},"id":"d25dde36-76cb-44aa-a649-b1f61bb3bebb"}]}}],"requestId":"16727804366400067692"}`

**Skill response**

`{"requestId":"16727804366400067692","payload":{"devices":{"d25dde36-76cb-44aa-a649-b1f61bb3bebb":{"online":true,"currentFanSpeedSetting":"medium","on":true}}}}`

**Google home speaker**

Sorry, I am unable to reach the living room fan right now. Please try again.

Although the message returned back is compatible with the doc https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/traits/fanspeed#device-states, why the speaker doesn't return the "correct" message.

Thought the query for Fan OnOff is ok.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the query you said?

Comment: I use 2 queries:
1. what speed is the living room fan? 
2. What speed are the fans in the living room?  [I put the living room fan to "living room" room.

Comment: @NickFelker any update :)

Comment: I've set up the [smart home sample](https://github.com/actions-on-google/smart-home-nodejs) and those work for me. I'm returning `{"requestId":"16205761358062464243","payload":{"devices":{"0":{"online":true,"on":false,"currentFanSpeedSetting":"3","fanSpeed":"3"}}}}`

Comment: I think `fanSpeed` is extraneous, and my naming scheme is based on the `speed_name` parameter.

Is it possibly a timeout issue, where you're not able to respond fast enough?

Comment: Uhm, that's strange, those responses seem matching.
Btw, the queries are returned within 100ms

```
2018/09/17 02:11:21 GAResponse {"requestId":"1279815482385668649","payload":{"devices":{"d25dde36-76cb-44aa-a649-b1f61bb3bebb":{"online":true,"currentFanSpeedSetting":"high","on":true}}}}
2018/09/17 02:11:21 "POST http://127.0.0.1:3001/sh HTTP/1.0" from 172.17.0.1:52806 - 200 157B in 68.143687ms
```

Comment: Finally, find the reason: I missed the reversible in sync. Although sync went well, validator passed https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/tools/validator/, and I can turn on/off as well as query for on, the speed function went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

reversible trait is mandatory. If attributes are incomplete, the trait is not active.

If '[reversible](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/traits/fanspeed)' trait set to true, this device supports blowing the fan in both directions and can accept the command to reverse fan direction.